# Is it possible to disable mods when events happen in game?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I’m in the middle of some mod pack development for minecraft and I’m having problems with mods conflicting when I open an inventory. Would it be possible to disable a mod through the config when that specific type of inventory is opened? In my case it’s conflict between the Dank mod and Inventory Sorter.

The pack is 1.18.